# What is the latest recommendation on method max lines?

Tags: java

In the past years, I read more and more texts on beautiful code which recommend limiting the number of lines in some method.

Some say that the method should fit in 1 screen (did not say what screen size thou), the other say it should be max 40 lines, the third ones say it does not matter as long as it's easy to follow, etc.

Now, this becomes too confusing to follow. What is the latest recommendation on the maximum lines a method should have?

Comment: Off topic on SO - this is a discussion on programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133404/what-is-the-ideal-length-of-a-method

Comment: As many as are nessissary and no more. Im not sure this question has an answer; only opinions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's not written in stone but as a rule of thumb I would suggest 5-10 lines. If it's more than 10 lines ask yourself if you can split it. Usually you'd be able to split.

Try to avoid "Geographical code" - A code with many if/switch that each if-block contains many lines. Usually the inner logic of each "if" in such case can be externalized to a different method.

If you have 2 loops (not nested loop) - usually each loop (or the logic of the loop) can be externalized.

Answer (score 1):

You should do what you believe is sensible limit.  There is no hard rule.

If you see mixed views on a topic it usually means there is no definitive answer and it is a matter of taste instead.  I suggest you pick a suggestion, or make up your own.

You can say that a method should not compile to more then 65535 bytes as it won't compile.

Comment: I like to use Avogadro's Number as my standard.  I love physics...

Comment: @duffymo have you ever exceed your limit? ;)

Comment: `6.02214*10^23` ...........

Comment: I use something closer to Avocado's number. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Avocado's%20Number&defid=6922903

Comment: Yours is a delicious standard.  I've never exceeded mine - no problem!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the actual length matters, as long as the method's code logically belongs together.

You should try to avoid duplicating code by extracting it to a private method, but it doesn't make sense to divide a long method to parts just because of some "length recommendation".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has ever changed in my view:

A method should have as many lines as it requires to achieve the single goal that the method aims to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Clean Code - Robert C. Martin 
suggests to give a method as few lines as possible (can't remeber the rule but like 8 lines). It's also important that a method should only be responsible for a single exercise

Comment: Personally I think Bob's advice contradicts itself: As few lines as possible; but no more than x!

Comment: @StuPointerException No rule without exception. It's a guideline not a gun on your chest.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be a problem on the number of lines, but about making concise and well-defined functions.

There are other interesting questions about this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129599/best-rule-for-maximum-function-size

[When is a function too long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475675/when-is-a-function-too-long)